# Missing HttpParameterBinding and ParameterBindingAttribute

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm investigating Web Api in ASP.NET vNext using the daily builds.  In a web api 2x project, I use HttpParameterBinding and ParameterBindingAttribute in some situations (see http://bit.ly/1sxAxdk); however, I can't seem to find either in vNext.  Do/will these classes exist?  If not, what are my alternatives?

Edit (1-22-15):

I want to be able to serialize a complex JS object to a JSON string, put the JSON string in a hidden form field (say name="data"), submit the form, and then bind my parameter to that JSON object on the server.  This will never be done by a human, but rather by a machine.  I also want this very same mechanism to work if the JSON is sent directly in the request body instead of form data.  I also need this to work for several different types of objects.

I've been able to accomplish this scenario in Web Api 2.2 in a few different ways, including a custom ModelBinder; however, I remember reading an MSFT blog post that suggested to use a ModelBinder for query string binding, formatters for request body, and HttpParameterBinding for more general scenarios.  Is it okay to read the request body in a ModelBinder ASP.NET 5, or is there a better mechanism for that?  If so, then case closed and I will port my ModelBinder with a few minor changes.

I'm not sure that IInputFormatter will work for me in this case either.

Comment: There is no more ParameterBindingAttribute. You can create a custom modelbinder and register it. Or in your case it might be that you can just use [FromForm]. If you can provide a more detailed example in your question, I might be able to help with an actual sample sample.

Example for what we call greedy model binder can be found at:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding/Binders/HeaderModelBinder.cs

And registration is as simple as
services.SetupOptions<MvcOptions>(options => options.ModelBinders.Insert(0, new YourCustomBinder());

Comment: Thanks Yishai!  I've updated my original question.

Comment: IInputFormatter will work just fine. I posted a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here are two rough approaches

## Approach 1:

A quick and dirty approach would be to start with a Dto model

```
public class Dto
{
    public Serializable Result { get; set; }

    public Serializable FromForm
    {
        get { return Result; }
        set { Result = value; }
    }

    [FromBody]
    public Serializable FromBody
    {
        get { return Result; }
        set { Result = value; }
    }
}

public class Serializable
{
}
```

And an action method

```
public IActionResult DoSomething(Dto dto)
{
   // Do something with Dto.Result
}
```

Then write a custom model binder for Serializable, that just works with  `Request.Form` this way you never actually read the body yourself, and `Form` only reads it if it of type Form.

The down side of this is that ApiExplorer will not provide correct details (but I think since this is none-standard you are going to be in trouble here anyways).

## Approach 2

You can alternatively just use the code from `BodyModelBinder` and create a custom binder for `Serializable` type above, that first tries to get it from the Form, and if it fails tries to get it from the Body. The `Dto` class in that case is not necessary.

Here is some pseudo code

```
if (inputType is yourtype)
{
     if (request.Form["yourkey"] != null)
     {
         Use Json.Net to deserialize your object type
     }
     else
     {
         fall back to BodyModelBinder code
     }
}
```

With this approach you can make it generic, and ApiExplorer will say the way to bind the type is unknown/custom (we haven't decided on the term yet :) )

**Note:**

Instead of registering the model binder you can use the [ModelBinder(typeof(customBinder))] attribute to apply it sparingly.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/08b83fefc338971421c14673aaa744fabfea05eb/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ModelBinders/BodyModelBinder.cs) to the `BodyModelBinder` code.

Comment: Thanks, approach #2 is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

There is a new [FromHeader] attribute that allows you to bind directly to http header values if that is what you need.

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1671

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=fromheader

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but I actually need something a bit different.  I suppose that I should have clarified, and I will edit my original question.